# Product title below the thumbnail in Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

How to make the text with the name of the product in the woocommerce email be below the product image?
I want the letters to look good.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated:** If the product image are displayed in your email notifications, you can try the following to display the product title under this image:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'product_title_under_thumbnail_emails', 10, 3 );
function product_title_under_thumbnail_emails( $item_name, $item, $is_visible ) {
    // Targeting view order pages only
    if( is_wc_endpoint_url() )
        return $item_name;

    // Get the WC_Product object (from order item)
    $product = $item->get_product();

    if( $product->get_image_id() > 0 && $is_visible )
        $item_name = '<br>' . $item_name;

    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.